# onmouseover ,onmouseout not working?

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
```

> script is not working

```
<script>

function show(inp,spanId){


var msg=document.getElementById(spanId);

msg.innerHTML="<font color="red" size="6">",inp.id;

}

function hide(spanId){
var msg=document.getElementById(spanId);
msg.innerHTML="";
}
</script>
```

> function not working properly

```
<input type='text' id='name' onmouseover="show(this,namemessage)" onmouseout="hide(namemessage)" />

<span id='namemessage'></span>
<br/>
<input type='text' id='email' onmouseover="show(this,emailmessage)" />

<span id='emailmessage'></span>



<body>
```

```js
function show(inp, spanId) {


  var msg = document.getElementById(spanId);
  msg.innerHTML = '<font color="red" size="6">'+inp.id+'</font>';

}

function hide(spanId) {
  var msg = document.getElementById(spanId);
  msg.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='name' onmouseover="show(this,'namemessage')" onmouseout="hide('namemessage')" />

<span id='namemessage'></span>
<br/>
<input type='text' id='email' onmouseover="show(this,'emailmessage')" />

<span id='emailmessage'></span>
```

Comment: Explain a bit what your problem is and how you want us to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what do you want to do with this code but there are many errors in your code.
check below your code without errors

```
<input type='text' id='name' onmouseover="return show(this,'namemessage')" onmouseout="return hide('namemessage')" />

<span id='namemessage'></span>
<br/>
<input type='text' id='email' onmouseover="return show(this,'emailmessage')" />

<span id='emailmessage'></span>
<script>

function show(inp,spanId){
var msg=document.getElementById(spanId);
msg.innerHTML='<font color="red" size="6">'+inp.id+'</font>';
}

function hide(spanId){
var msg=document.getElementById(spanId);
msg.innerHTML="";
}
</script>
```